# Stack Exchange Connecting to Redis Cluster Connection error

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to connect our asp.net application through Stack exchange client to Redis Cluster, but I am getting an connection error shown below :

No connection is available to service this operation:

I am using the connection string :

< add key="SearchCacheRedisConnectionString" value="IP:6379,IP:6379,connectTimeout=1000,abortConnect=false,ConnectRetry=3,syncTimeout=500,keepAlive=180" />

I have used the same connection string to connect to a **standalone redis instance** and everything works perfectly.

Its only when i try to connect to a cluster ( 3 master 3 slave ) architecture that i am getting a connection error.

Is there a different connection string i am supposed to use to connect to a **Redis Cluster** or is there any specific changes i am supposed to make in my code to connect to a **Cluster**.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could your connectTimeout be too low? The StackExchange.Redis default is 5000